# GestureListener is not recognized

Tags: java, android

I have a

- custom `View` with a circle in it
- `MainActivity`

I am displaying the custom `View`, which works. I can see the circle.

I have implemented the `OnGestureListener` in the `View`, but it is not recognized. All the gesture methods are never called.

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

`MainActivity`:

```
package com.example.testpath;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(getResourceId("main","id"));
        WorldMap worldmap = new WorldMap(this);
        rlayout.addView(worldmap);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public int getResourceId(String pVariableName, String pResourcename) 
    {
        try {
            return getResources().getIdentifier(pVariableName, pResourcename, getPackageName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        } 
    }
}
```

Custom `View`:

```
package com.example.testpath;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class WorldMap  extends View implements OnGestureListener{

//  private GestureDetector gestureScanner;

    static float translatex = -2200;
    static float translatey = -1500;

    public WorldMap(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           super.onDraw(canvas);
           Paint paint = new Paint();
           canvas.translate(translatex,translatey);
           paint.setColor(Color.RED);
           canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 50, paint);
           paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
           canvas.drawCircle(2290, 1590, 50, paint);
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.v("DEBUG TEST", "onDown ");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.v("DEBUG TEST", "onShowPress ");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("DEBUG TEST", "onSingleTapUp ");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float vx = e1.getRawX();
        float vy = e1.getRawY();
        Log.v("DEBUG TEST", "onScroll : " + vx + " " + vy);
        translatex=translatex+vx;
        translatey=translatey+vy;
        invalidate();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.v("DEBUG TEST", "onLongPress ");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("DEBUG TEST", "onFling ");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a `GestureDetector` in `WorldMap`:

```
private GestureDetector detector;
```

Initialize it:

```
public WorldMap(Context context) {
    super(context);
    detector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
}
```

And override `onTouchEvent()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    detector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Check out the developer's guide on [Detecting Common Gestures](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html).